# Javascript clear pre-entered text in textbox upon click

Tags: javascript

I have the following code below that I would like to have automatically clear the pre-entered text "Enter port # here" when the user clicks in the textbox, but I am unsure how I would go about doing this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function portredirect() {
    var domain = document.domain;
    var port = prompt("Please enter the port # you would like to connect to, and press OK. You will be automatically redirected", "Enter port # here");
    if (port != null && port != "" && port != "Enter port # here") {
        window.open("http://" + domain + ":" + port, '_blank');
    }
}</script>
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your HTML code as well :)

Comment: Use placeholder tag for the html element. It will not work for ie with version prior to 9

Comment: You can't add event listeners inside a prompt. Better you let the field empty.

Comment: You have no control over the [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) window other than when it opens via the call to `prompt`, what text shows in it (in the title and text box), and the return value once the user has finished interacting with it, because it is an OS-level UI element produced by the browser. It's probably better to just leave the text input's initial text as an empty string.

Comment: I would suggest if you need to create a customised prompt window that you look at something like jQueryUI to create a fully customisable html prompt window see the docs for [JqueryUI Dialog's](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt` UI is controlled by the operating system and browser. You have no control over it. The same goes for `<select>` and `<input type="file" />` although mostly for familiarity and safety.

Perhaps try some library like Impromptu, JQuery Alert Dialogs, and others.